# How to reach Ahmedabad to Thane by train?

Tags: trains, public-transport, india, indian-railways, mumbai

I will be travelling to Mumbai and from my company Thane is the nearest railway station. I will be travelling from Ahmedabad, Gujarat.

Can any one help me find the best train to travel?

Should I reach to Mumbai Central and then travel to Thane by local train or any direct train is available?

I will prefer super fast or express trains only. I tried google but no one can help better than experienced travelers.

Comment: Surprising you want to travel by train and didn't bother to check irctc or indianrail ?

Comment: @DumbCoder I have tried the sites but it only suggest Ahmedabad Passenger Train which is not useful to me.

Comment: Why don't you take any of the express trains going to any of the suburbs of Mumbai i.e. Kalyan/Borivalli etc and then take the local from there ? If you go to Mumbai Central you have to again come to the same local station on your way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As someone who regularly visited that route (Ahmedabad to Thane), I advise you take an overnight train (preferably Gujarat Mail) or ADI-BCT superfast. Choose the one that has a halt at Borivali (Duranto doesn't; it has only one stop: Mumbai Central). For morning, double-decker is a good option. This is because Thane is located to the east of Mumbai and commute by trains, whether local or inter-state, does get cumbersome.

Just outside from the Borivali station(East), take bus number **700** which spans the entire run of Ghodbunder highway covering all the major areas in Thane from West to its last stop at Thane Station East.

However, if you decide to stick to trains, get down at any of the major western Mumbai stations (Borivali-Andheri-Dadar-Central) and take a local to Dadar. From there, change the platform to Central line and take a train to Thane.

**DO NOT** take the passenger as it takes around 23 hours to get there.

Comment: That is correct. I am preferring over the night journey. I also found another route as take Lokshakti Express from Ahmedabad or Maninagar railway station, it's last stop is Bandra Terminus. You can leave the train at Andheri station which is just before the Bandra Terminus and go for Metro train from Andheri to Ghatkopar. Catch the local train from Ghatkopar to Thane.
Also you can travel upto Bandra Terminus and from there go to Bandra local station, catch the train up to Dadar, after reaching Dadar change to Dadar Central platform and catch another local to Thane on central line.

Comment: But don't be surprised if unreserved ticket holders share the seats with you in the initial and final legs of journey in Lokshakti as this train is a darling to the daily commuters. Also, better board it from Ahmedabad main station as Maninagar doesn't have a longer halt.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Ahmedabad/Th%C4%81ne):

[image: route]

A faster alternative is to fly to Mumbai and take a local train there.